# How to fix invalid name pattern: SCHEMA_NAME:VARCHAR_ARRAY

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have dropped and created a TYPE using

```
drop type VARCHAR_ARRAY force;

create or replace
TYPE varchar_array AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

and i am having a stored `proc` which takes `varchar_array` as `IN` parameter and am getting `DBException:invalid name pattern: SCHEMA_NAME:VARCHAR_ARRAY`.
Can anyone let me know where am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you seeing that in? It would get a bind variable error in the current version; if I've interpreted what you're doing right, since you haven't shown the procedure specification. Or is this in a `createDescriptor` call, and nothing to do with SQL Developer?

Comment: Its in createDescriptor call  ArrayDescriptor carrier_array_descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("VARCHAR_ARRAY", conn); . Please find the calling statemen